# Change the location of tsconfig.app.json

Tags: angular, typescript, command-line-interface, angular-cli

I can change the location of files tsconfig.app.json and tsconfig.spec.json? I want to put these files inside `src/config` folder. But qhen i try, the Terminal show me an error.

#### Versions

```
Windows 10
NPM 5.6.0
Node 6.11.4
NG 5.2
```

#### Repro steps

- Put the file `tsconfig.app.json` inside config folder
- Change the location of `tsconfig.json` inside `extends` into tsconfig.app.json
- Run the start of project

#### Observed behavior

Return the error:

```
ERROR in TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
    at createSourceFile (C:\Users\bruno.dulcetti\Repositorios\tfs\_componentes\Base.Template.Angular\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:12619:109)
    at parseSourceFileWorker (C:\Users\bruno.dulcetti\Repositorios\tfs\_componentes\Base.Template.Angular\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:12551:26)
    at Object.parseSourceFile (C:\Users\bruno.dulcetti\Repositorios\tfs\_componentes\Base.Template.Angular\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:12477:26)
    at Object.createSourceFile (C:\Users\bruno.dulcetti\Repositorios\tfs\_componentes\Base.Template.Angular\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:12318:29)
    at new TypeScriptFileRefactor (C:\Users\bruno.dulcetti\Repositorios\tfs\_componentes\Base.Template.Angular\node_modules\@ngtools\webpack\src\refactor.js:79:35)
    at Object.resolveEntryModuleFromMain (C:\Users\bruno.dulcetti\Repositorios\tfs\_componentes\Base.Template.Angular\node_modules\@ngtools\webpack\src\entry_resolver.js:108:20)
    at Promise.resolve.then.then (C:\Users\bruno.dulcetti\Repositorios\tfs\_componentes\Base.Template.Angular\node_modules\@ngtools\webpack\src\angular_compiler_plugin.js:255:54)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:109:7)
    at Module.runMain (module.js:606:11)
    at run (bootstrap_node.js:383:7)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:149:9)
    at bootstrap_node.js:496:3
```

My file `tsconfig.app.json`:

```
{
    "extends": "../../tsconfig.json",
    "compilerOptions": {
        "outDir": "../../out-tsc/app",
        "baseUrl": "../",
        "module": "es2015",
        "types": []
    },
    "exclude": [
        "test.ts",
        "../**/*.spec.ts"
    ]
}
```

#### Desired behavior

I don't use the CLI.

Regards.

Comment: If you don't use CLI, you need to somehow tell the tool you that you are using to find the config file...

Comment: Describe repro steps more detailed from scratch. How do you build your project?

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you could try changing the path/name to tsconfig.app.json in the app definition in .angular-cli.json in the root folder of your project